# Deezer API playlist search : strict mode

Tags: api, search, playlist, deezer

The API seems to have a little problem.

When strict mode is off :
http://api.deezer.com/search/playlist?q=vieille%20charrue

When strict mode is on :
http://api.deezer.com/search/playlist?q=vieille%20charrue&strict=on

According to the documentation, when the strict parameter is set to "on", the fuzziness must be removed.

In fact, there is no fuzziness when not using this parameter ( or if strict mode to "off" ) and the fuzziness is added when I set this value to on ...

Seems to be a small bug, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the strict mode allows you to correct the spelling of your search.

Hence, ***?q=vieille%20charrue*** will return no data since there is no playlist called 'vielle charrue'.

However, if you add an S like this : http://api.deezer.com/search/playlist?q=vieilles%20charrue , you will get the same result as http://api.deezer.com/search/playlist?q=vieille%20charrue&strict=on

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for answering, but this answer is not correct.
According to the documentation :
strict  Disable the fuzzy mode (?strict=on)

I'm expecting, when I add the strict=on parameter, to have fuzziness disabled, not enabled.
The current behaviour is wrong, according to the documentation and also according to the common sense :)

Comment: Au vu du prénom, j'imagine d'ailleurs que je peux échanger en français :) J'avais bien saisi le comportement actuel de l'API, je signale justement que ce n'est pas le comportement normal, attendu et documenté, il est exactement inversé actuellement

Comment: En effet, pour le moment c'est inversé, on va corriger cela pour que ça soit plus parlant. Merci pour le report !


English version : 
Indeed, this way of working doesn't make sense. A fix will be done to correct it. Thanks for reporting !

Comment: Merci pour le fix, je peux confirmer que les résultats sont comme attendus désormais :)